# How can I use style-loader in react SSR (Server Side Rendering)?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader, server-side-rendering

As you know, we can easily use style-loader to add our styles to our react project, but the **window** is not available in Server Side Rendering, so how I can use style-loader (or something instead of that in SSR project)?

When I use *style-loader*, it returns this error as expected:

```
 .../public/server.js:866
        return window && document && document.all && !window.atob;
        ^

    ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just found an answer to my question; We can use [isomorphic-style-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-style-loader) for loading styles in SSR

Comment: Hey man, I did exactly what the link showed but I get the message `No PostCSS Config found in ...\css`. Did you get this error too?

Comment: @kabison33 to solve this error you need to add to your project `postcss.config.js` file

Comment: this doesn't support react 18  anyone have any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

An update to something more recent - I hope it will help someone

For react 18 the lab 'isomorphic-style-loader' wont work (does not have support).

There is a new lab that has support for react 18 which does the same thing: ['isomorphic-style-loader-react18'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-style-loader-react18)

P.S - you will need to install 'postcss-loader' as well.