# Navigator reference not found in application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Have references to `navigator` in multiple logics within our `React` project.

For example:

in MyComponent.jsx

```
export const isMobileDevice = /android|iPad|iPhone|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
```

These all works fine.

But when we perform a build using `webpack`, end up with following error.

```
log: ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
at Module../src/components/MyComponent.jsx (project-name@3.22.0:25348:21)
at __webpack_require__ (project-name@3.22.0:25348:30)
```

Seen few similar queries in past such as follows:

[Window is not defined after a build with Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55849240/window-is-not-defined-after-a-build-with-webpack)

[Webpack 4 for SSR, How to solve this ReferenceError: window is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52618679/webpack-4-for-ssr-how-to-solve-this-referenceerror-window-is-not-defined)

They all come down to adding the following in the `wepack` config as follows:

`globalObject: 'this'`

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  performance: {
    maxAssetSize: 1500, 
    maxEntrypointSize: 1500,
  },
  output: {
    globalObject: 'this', // this is what i added. There is nothing else in my webpack config file.
  },
};
```

After I deleted all generated files like `.webpack-stats.client.json` and `.webpack-stats.server.json` files.
And run `npm run build`, the error still remains.

What am I missing?

package.json (related dependencies for webpack)

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "our-company-key": {
    "bundler": {
      "webpackConfigPath": "webpack.config.js"
    },
  },
  "scripts": {
    // other scripts
    "build": "company-build-using-webpack"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.11",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.39.3",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack-command": "^0.5.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2",
    "webpack-serve": "^2.0.2"
  },
}
```