# Laravel mix - 'window is not defined' with style-loader in target: node

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix, webpack-style-loader

I have 2 different builds for my laravel-mix. Target node and web. Here is what how they look like:

```
if (process.env.npm_config_section === 'server') {
    mix.js('resources/js/app-server.js', 'public/js')
        .webpackConfig({
            target: 'node',
            plugins: [
                new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
                    maxChunks: 1,
                })
            ],
        })
        .mergeManifest()
        .version();
} else if (process.env.npm_config_section === 'client') {
    mix.js('resources/js/app-client.js', 'public/js')
        .webpackConfig({
            target: 'web',
            output: {
                chunkFilename: 'js/chunks/[name].js?id=[chunkhash]',
                publicPath: '/',
            },
        })
        .mergeManifest()
        .version();
}

mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
```

- For 'web' - it separates the chunks
- For 'node' - it only gives  1 file

However, I get an error for 'node' which is fair enough - we don't have window in node target:

> return window && document && document.all && !window.atob
>
> ReferenceError: window is not defined

Looking at the compiled file this is where it is crashing which made me think it's style-loader related.

```
var isOldIE = memoize(function () {
    // Test for IE <= 9 as proposed by Browserhacks
    // @see http://browserhacks.com/#hack-e71d8692f65334173fee715c222cb805
    // Tests for existence of standard globals is to allow style-loader
    // to operate correctly into non-standard environments
    // @see https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader/issues/177
    return window && document && document.all && !window.atob;
});
```

What can I do so that 'node' doesn't use style-loader? How can I change this in laravel-mix?

- [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55093457/4705339) says use [MiniCssExtractPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin)
- [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51570134/how-can-i-use-style-loader-in-react-ssr-server-side-rendering) says use [isomorphic-style-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-style-loader) or [node-style-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-style-loader)

...but to change the style-loader in Laravel-mix based on target?

Answer (score -1):

Not including `mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')` in node target worked :O

Comment: That doesn't work. Including or not mix.sass(...), the isOldIE() function is sill in the output JS code and the error keeps showing.